# Java8 Streams: How to preserve the value before map to be accessed by collect/groupingBy functions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Java8 Streams to iterate through a list and for each of the element I invoke `map` and then I need to aggregate the results. My problem is that when I call `groupingBy` I also need to access the original object before calling `map`. Here is a snippet:

```
list.stream() //
          .filter(item -> item.getType() == HUMAN) //
          .map(item -> manager.itemToHuman(item.getId())) //
          .filter(Objects::nonNull) //
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Human::getAge, Collectors.summarizingLong(item.getCount())));
```

The problem is with the call to `Collectors.summarizingLong(item.getCount())` since `item` at this point is NOT accessible. Is there an elegant way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing `map()` stream transformed into `Stream<Human>` so you can't use `item` object in the collector.

You can transform `item` into a pair of `Human` object and `count` using `SimpleEntry` then use it on the collector.

```
list.stream() 
    .filter(item -> item.getType() == HUMAN) 
    .map(item -> 
        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(manager.itemToHuman(item.getId()), item.getCount()))
    .filter(entry -> Objects.nonNull(entry.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().getAge(), 
             Collectors.summarizingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: Or, with Java ≥ 9, you could use `Map.entry(...)` instead of `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(...)`.